# Set button's width to star

Tags: wpf

I have a button with a custom style used in all my application. This style has the following property :

```
<Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
```

But on a particular page I need to have my button stretched to its parent. I would like this to do something like to "cancel" the 150 width :

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" Width="*" />
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: If your button has a style, but you then also use width on that button, then the width which comes from that style is ignored. There is nothing esle you need to do.

Comment: Sizing an object is usually dependent on the parent panel holding the object. The most a control can influence it without something like rewriting a control template is setting `HorizontalAlignment=Stretch`

Answer (score 1):

Try the default value: `Double.NaN`. In XAML it is:

```
Width="Auto"
```

From Remarks of [FrameworkElement.Width Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> In addition to acceptable Double values, this property can also be
>   Double.NaN. This is how you specify auto sizing behavior. In XAML you
>   set the value to the string "Auto" (case insensitive) to enable the
>   auto sizing behavior. Auto sizing behavior implies that the element
>   will fill the width available to it.

Comment: Auto will size the button depending on its content, in my case.

Comment: Then remember @Rachels suggestion: combine it with `HorizontalAlignment=Stretch`

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyStyle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>


  <Button Content="fdfdfg">
      <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
        </Style>
      </Button.Style>          
  </Button>
```

Comment: Yes and you can just set it to Auto like @LPL said , i just thought i'll show you how you can inherit from a style. possibly you would wan't to some trigger to change this value..